# How can I tell if a request is made with AJAX in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, kohana

I've tried these

```
request::is_ajax()

Request::instance()->is_ajax
```

To no avail. I've noticed in the `request` class there is a public property `$is_ajax` but I can't seem to be able to access the property.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: request::is_ajax() should do it, can you provide some more context from which you're calling it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use this:

```
if (Request::$is_ajax OR $this->request !== Request::instance())
{ .. }
```

That way you know that it's an ajax- or ajax-like-request

I use this in my controller base-class so I know whether or not to render the full or partial view.

Answer (score 9):

in case anyone comes back to this, in Kohana 3.1 it is now `$this->request->is_ajax(`) if you are in a controller.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up getting it to work with `Request::$is_ajax`

Seems they've gotten rid of the function, and are now relying on a public property.